# How to use std::vector or other container in cgo of golang?

Tags: go, cgo

I want to malloc large number of objects in to memory.(about 100 million objects) because the gc of golang is not effective enough,so i need to use c/c++ to malloc memory and use std::vector to hold objects.
this is my code,i want use std container in cgo:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

void dosome(){
    vector<int> ivec;   // empty vector
    for (vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix != 10; ++ix)
        ivec[ix] = ix; // disaster: ivec has no elements
}

*/
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++
import "C"

//import "fmt"
func main() {

    C.dosome()

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

and have error message below:

```
go run stddemo.go 
# command-line-arguments
./stddemo.go:13:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
#include <vector>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

how can i set the include path or is there another idea?

Answer (score 6):

While you can use C++ with CGo, you can't embed that code inside the `.go` file, since it ultimately gets built with a C compiler.

Instead, place your `dosome` function in a separate `.cpp` file in the same directory as the `.go` file, and declare your function to use C linkage.  For example:

```
extern "C" {
    void dosome() {
        vector<int> ivec;
        ...
    }
}
```

If you include a prototype for the function in the CGo comment in the `.go` file so you can call it from Go.

Since you have multiple files now, you can't use the `go run foo.go` shorthand any more (since it only compiles a single file).  Instead, you will need to use `go run package` or `go build package`, where your code is located at `$GOPATH/src/package`.

Comment: but it seems that cgo is very slower?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272285/why-is-cgos-performance-is-so-slow-is-there-something-wrong-with-my-testing-co

Answer (score 4):

Uhh I think your conclusions are a bit too fast. GC cost is driven by two things: The more garbage your program produces, the more the GC will have to run. Second: The more pointers there are to scan, the longer a single GC will take.

That is to say: as long as you put your 100 million things into a go slice and keep them there: the GC won't have to run much, because there's no garbage. And second: if your things don't contain pointers, GC time, should it still occur, will be fine.

So, my question is: do your things have pointers?

Comment: thank you very much. It seems that i totally go to the wrong way!

Comment: cgo function seems much more slower than go function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272285/why-is-cgos-performance-is-so-slow-is-there-something-wrong-with-my-testing-co

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to call someone's golang code this is a quick ram inefficient way:

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func intArrayFromC (src unsafe.Pointer, sz int) []uint64 {
    dest := make([]uint64, sz)
    copy(dest, (*(*[1000000000]uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(src)))[:sz:sz])// big number dose not affect ram.
    return dest
}

//export doPrint
func doPrint(src unsafe.Pointer, sz int){
    var numbers []uint64 = intArrayFromC(src, sz);

    for i := 0; i < len(numbers); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d  index: %d\n", numbers[i], i)
    }
}

func main() {}
```

and the c++ code:

```
#include "print.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<GoUint64> numbers{99,44,11,00,2,33,44};

    while (1) {
        doPrint(numbers.data(), numbers.size());
    }
    return 0;
}
```