# Comparing Go Win32 syscall and cgo: does it have the same overhead?

Tags: go, winapi, system-calls, cgo

In Windows, this is the most common way to call a Win32 function (resumed steps to call [GetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) function):

```
dllUser32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
GetForegroundWindow := dllUser32.NewProc("GetForegroundWindow")
hwnd, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(proc.GetForegroundWindow.Addr(), 0,
    0, 0, 0)
```

I understand why [cgo is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272990), and that cgo isn't used with Win32 calls, but with other C code. But now my question is: how can I compare the code above to a cgo call, in terms of overhead?

Does it use cgo under the hood?

Does it have the same overhead of a cgo call?

Comment: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) answers those questions for you.

Comment: @IInspectable How can I make Compiler Explorer compile a Windows Go code?