# Best way to deal with namespaces on cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I’m working on a project that makes usage of some C++ libraries, this libraries use namespaces like:

```
namespace ns {
    void hello();
}
```

All compiles, and I can use the functions out of namespaces, but I can’t find docu about how to work with namespaces in order to access to this method from Go.
    My first idea was to use a small wrapper using the cgo comments like:
    package stuff

```
// #import <some_libs.h>
/*
void hello() {
    ns::hello();
}
*/
import “C”
```

But this fails with an:

> error: expected expression before ‘:'

another option is to prepare the wrapper out of the .go file, but this is going to make a bit more complicated the installation, etc of the libraries.
    What is the best approach?, can I just call to this method using the C lib? something like: C.ns.hello()??

Thanks!,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28263846/1643939